# Looking for a $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of sets containing $1$

Tags: measure-theory

Let's consider the following set
$$\mathcal{S} = \{S \subset \mathbb{R}: 1 \in S \}.$$

I would like to find $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$. I think that $\sigma(\mathcal{S}) = \mathcal{P(\mathbb{R})}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set. I have even proved it.

The first inclusion, that is $\sigma(\mathcal{S}) \subset \mathcal{P(\mathbb{R})}$, is trivial. The second one is a bit more tricky. Let's grab $P \in \mathcal{P(\mathbb{R})}$. There are two options:

1. $1 \in P$, then $A \in \mathcal{S}$ and that implies $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{S})$,
2. $1 \notin P$, then $1 \in P^C$ thus $P^C \in \sigma(\mathcal{S})$ which implies that $P \in \sigma(\mathcal{S})$.

These options implies that $\mathcal{P(\mathbb{R})} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{S})$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your title does not match the body of your question. Is $\mathcal{S}$ the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $1$ or the set of all *intervals* containing $1$?

Comment: @SangchulLee, true. I believe it is better now.

Comment: Now your reasoning seems correct. :)

Comment: @SangchulLee, thank you very much. I thought it is correct however I needed some confirmation.